# javascript: Auto calculate price upon entering quantity in input box

Tags: javascript

In my program I am trying to auto calculate total price when user enter quantity in input box. For that I performed below script. but due to some error my script doesn't working as per expectation and when I enter quantity, total price doesn't get updated. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code. I want to perform this script without jquery.

code:

```html
  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="" method="POST" name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <table bgcolor="pink" align="center" border="2px">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <th> Category </th>
     <th> Description </th>
     <th> Unit Price </th>
     <th> Quantity </th>
     <th> Total Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1</td>
     <td> Paneer </td>
     <td name="priceQ1"> $10 </td>
     <td> <input type="text" size="4" id="q1" name="qty1" onkeyup="calculate()"> </td>
     <td> <input type="text" id="total1" name="total1"> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> Rice </td>
     <td name="priceQ2"> $30 </td>
     <td> <input type="text" size="4" id="q2" name="qty2" onkeyup="calculate()"> </td>
     <td> <input type="text" id="total2" name="total2"> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr align="right">
     <td colspan="4"> Subtotal $ </td>
     <td> <input type="text" id="sub_total" name="sub_total"> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">2</td>
     <td> Chicken Palak </td>
     <td name="priceQ3"> $20 </td>
     <td> <input type="text" size="4" id="q3" name="qty3"  onkeyup="calculate()"> </td>
     <td> <input type="text" id="total3" name="total3"> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> Aloo Tikki </td>
     <td name="priceQ4 "> $14 </td>
     <td> <input type="text" size="4" id="q4" name="qty4" onkeyup="calculate()"> </td>
     <td> <input type="text" id="total4" name="total4"> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr align="right">
     <td colspan="4"> Subtotal $ </td>
     <td> <input type="text" id="sub_total2" name="sub_total2"> </td> 
    </tr>
                </tbody>
  
  </table>
  <p align="center">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   <input type="reset">
  </p>
  </form> 

  <script>
   function calculate() {
    var f = document.forms['myForm'];
    
    for(var i=0;i<4;i++){ 
     var qty = document.getElementByName('qty'+i);  
     document.getElementById('total'+i).value = newValue; 
    }     
   }

  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should look at the browser console - your code is generating errors that will tell you why it's not working.

Comment: There is quite a lot wrong with the code. Firstly, there is no function document.getElementsById(). Only one element can have exact id. Open your browser developer tools and you can see all these problems. I would suggest to use classes instead of id-s and jQuery to make handling them much much easier.

Comment: @RauliRajande I want to perform without using jquery

Comment: @pari This is ok, but you just have to write a lot more code and have risk this to be broken every time, when there is a browser update. Instead of id use classes and getElementsByClassName() :)

Comment: @RauliRajande Can you please show me in code snippet to get better idea ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `document.getElementsById`, you should name your different quantities and total price fields with distinct names and traverse thru them using `document.getElementById('qty'+i);`

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
var qty = document.getElementByName('qty'+i);
....
document.getElementById('total'+i).value = newValue;
}`

Comment: @Erna There is different quantity for every item

Comment: of course, you should name the fields themselves accordingly. `<input type="text" size="4" id="q1" name="qty1" onkeyup="calculate()">` and `<input type="text" id="total1" name="total1">`

Comment: @ Eran Geva After for loop do I need to write any other line of code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157238/discussion-between-pari-and-eran-geva).